# php - webpage visted counter

Tags: php

I am fetching the data from database and displaying near Home link , what i want to do is when Home Link is clicked it should go to next page and where the counter for that page is incremented and again updated in database .THAT is how many time that page is been visted

So my problem is since the while loop is run and as per match the record while be fetch from database . so now i want to determined how many time the link is clicked for each record displayed and store in database

```
<?php 

$i = 1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($strSql))
  {

?>

<div id="menubar">
        <ul>
            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="count.php" name="abc<?php $i; ?>">Home</a><?php $_SESSION['Home']=$row['ID']; echo $_SESSION['Home'];?></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you not just add a count at the top of each new page...?

Answer (score 0):

You could use separate record entries in db table for storing each link's counter.

So your table will contain

```
    title ------- number clicked ------- last click
    Home          10                     10/05/2011
```

Something like this. Or when you want to cache each visit. Use separate tables for each of the links.

and onclick pass a GET variable like

```
<a href="count.php?page=home">Home</a>
```

and store it on the respective table.